# Set different cron on magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab, magento-cron, cronjobs

**The problem is:**

I have a custom extension that has a file PHP setting to cron.

When it's running other cron like `m2epro` cron doesn't start. Is there a way to fix this **problem**?

If it can help you, I have **`AOE_Scheduler`** extension.